# SET STATISTICS TIME ON showing two rows when executing a statement with OPTION(RECOMPILE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a statement with OPTION(RECOMPILE) and I want to see how much time does the recompile actually take.

But when I switch on the time statistics :

> SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

I get multiple rows for a single statement:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
 CPU time = 15 ms, elapsed time = 15 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
 CPU time = 156 ms, elapsed time = 169 ms.
```

I am not sure which row represents the actual recompile time adn what is the other row

Answer (score 0):

The first result shows the time it takes to execute the first statement in your batch.

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
```

The second result shows how long it takes to execute the second statement in your batch.

```
DO something WITH OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: maybe i should have been more clear... i just set the statistics time once... so i am not actually SET STATISTICS TIME ON; everytime... I am just executing DO something WITH OPTION(RECOMPILE); and still seeing multiple lines in the output